# getJSON for NodeJS API answer

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I am learning NodeJS now. I have the following JavaScript code from a project:

```
$.getJSON('/api/' + entry + '/', function(data) {
            if ( data.hasOwnProperty("seq") ) {
                $(placement).append( data.seq );
            }
        });
```

It theoretically gets an answer from an Express NodeJS API, running at a specific port `XXXX`. The API can be accessed via `localhost:XXXX/api/whateverentry`.

The question is: how does this code know which port it should go?

Comment: If anyone looking for Nodejs API boilerplate with Expressjs and MongoDB. Try this: https://github.com/maitraysuthar/rest-api-nodejs-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will default to the current port that is being visited in the browser being used because it is a relative URL. If a different host is not specified, then the base of the URL will be used.

For example if you were running this on port 4000 on localhost, then going to `http://localhost:4000/api/...` is the same as the request above.

Answer (score 1):

A relative URL reference such as `/api` that doesn't start with `http://` or `https://` gets the protocol, port and domain from the host page URL.  So, your request will use the port number that the host page used.